# Why do we take opposite category when stating the Yoneda Lemma?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

> For any function $F: C^{op} \to \text{Set}$ and any object $X$ in $C$, natural transformations $\text{Hom}(-,X) \to F$ are in bijection with the elements in the set $F(x)$. That is,
>
> $\text{Nat} (\text{hom}(-,X),F ) \cong F(X)$

Why is that we consider the opposite category in the statement of the lemma?

Comment: Because $\mathrm{hom}(-,X)$ is contravariant. There is a statement of Yoneda's Lemma that describes the natural transformations for $\mathrm{hom}(X,-)$ and that one uses $C$, not $C^{\rm op}$.

Comment: Hmm I think I still don't get it. Maybe I should try reading the text again.

Comment: What text? You can think of presheafs $F : C^{op}→\mathrm{Set}$ as "imaginary elements" of $C$: you know what you want the maps from objects of $C$ to look like. So you can draw an element of $F(c)$ as an arrow $c→F$. Then the Yoneda lemma says that in the category of presheafs $C^{op}→\mathrm{Set}$, if you identify $c$ with the representable $\mathrm{Hom}(—,c)$, then you really have this property that morphisms $c→F$ are elements of $F(c)$.

Comment: You can do the same thing if you consider copresheafs $C→\mathrm{Set}$ if you prefer: if you have $F:C→\mathrm{Set}$ you want to think of elements of $F(c)$ as maps $c→F$.

Comment: Tai Danae's Categorical approach to topology @Dabouliplop

Comment: I haven't understood sheaf concept fully yet, could u explain in easier wordls pls

Comment: Ok, I can try. Let's try to give examples first. Do you know about products and limits? Let's say you have two objects $A$ and $B$ of a category $\mathbf{C}$. Given another object $X$, let $F(X)$ be the set of pairs of maps $X→A$ and $X→B$. Do you see why this defines a functor $\mathbf{C}^{op}→\mathrm{Set}$? (edit: I think it's good to understand presheafs first before looking at sheafs.)

Comment: you want to prove a result about natural transformations between things of the form $\hom(-, X)$ and $F$.  You can only have natural transformations between two functors if they have the same domain and codomain. $\hom(-, X) : C^{\text{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$, so $F$ had better be a functor $C^\text{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ too.

Comment: Hmmmm I don't .. I am totally lost oof @Dabouliplop . All I know is functor, co and contra and some misc stuff from reading Fong and Spivak's cat theory buch

Comment: Ah, sorry to confuse you... Then maybe it would be good to look at more introductory stuff rather than directly Yoneda's lemma without example. But I'm surprised the book you mention doesn't introduce limits and colimits (I don't have access to it though).

Comment: Hmm ill come back to this then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace $C$ with $C^{\text{op}}$ in the given statement, the fact that $(C^{\text{op}})^{\text{op}}=C$ gives you the Yoneda lemma for functors $C\to\text{Set}$ instead of $C^{\text{op}}\to\text{Set}$.

> For any functor $C\to\text{Set}$, natural transformations $\text{Hom}(X,-)\to F$ are in bijection with the elements of the set $F(x)$.

One change is that the relevant "Hom" functors are now $\text{Hom}(X,-)$ instead of $\text{Hom}(-,X)$. This switch happens because morphisms in the opposite category go the opposite direction. This is discusssed on pages 9 and 10 of your text.

The formulation for functors $C^{\text{op}}\to\text{Set}$ is preferred because it defines the Yoneda embedding: replacing objects and morphisms of $C$ with functors $\text{Hom}(-,X)$ and natural transformations between them gives a fully faithful functor from $C$ into the category of functors from $C^\text{op}\to\text{Set}$. This is pages 11-13 of your text at https://topology.mitpress.mit.edu/.